# Bash Profile Duplicate Python Paths

Tags: python, bash, path

I was editing my bash profile when I noticed my python path settings in the screenshot below. I don't remember explicitly editing my bash profile to be this way, and I'm just wondering how such a thing could've happened. Also, is it safe to delete two of the duplicates?

[Bash Profile Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va4he.png)

Comment: It is safe to delete the duplicate ones. Did you install Python from brew or somewhere multiple times?

Comment: That's probably it. I believe I was installing different versions of python and I might've mixed it up. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.